# Mongodb - db.shutdownserver() not working. Authentication error

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to shutdown mongodb so that I can convert it to a replica set, but I keep getting an error.

when using db.shutdownServer(), I get

```
 "errmsg" : "not authorized on admin to execute command
```

I tried "use admin" and then running the command, but issue still persists.
I saw another post where they said to use db.auth(username, password) but if I type that in cmd after connecting to cluster
When I try db.auth(username, password) replacing username and password with actual values
I get

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

I'm still new to mongodb so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you share the piece of code.

you can rewrite the above command with

passwordPrompt() option

db.auth( "username", passwordPrompt() )

or

mongo --username "" --password --  --authenticationMechanism SCRAM-SHA-256

Comment: I tried what you asked and it returned a 1, but db.shutdownServer() still doesn't work. Here's a screenshot https://postimg.cc/PpyqRZpf

Comment: @user6680 it's already replicaset on the screenshot. Also it's Atlas-hosted db - use Atlas UI/API to manage your cluster. Also shared tiers are shared between multiple users and have limited functionality in terms of admin commands.You cannot shut down a server that is being used by other people

Comment: Ok understood. I don't know what's telling you it's a replicaset from the screenshot though. My end goal is to get mongodb change streams working and it requires a replica set to be configured

Comment: @user6680 it is already configured. Run `rs.status()` to see members.

Comment: check the roles for your user "bob" or use admin 
and execute db.shutdownServer()